# Record syntax for QuasiQuoter constructor

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

The [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html#th-quasiquotation) for template Haskell says that `QuasiQuoter` is defined as

```
data QuasiQuoter = QuasiQuoter { quoteExp  :: String -> Q Exp,
                                 quotePat  :: String -> Q Pat,
                                 quoteType :: String -> Q Type,
                                 quoteDec  :: String -> Q [Dec] }
```

I have encountered examples such as `silly` shown below. How do they work given that they don't seem to fill in `quotePat`, `quoteType`, and `quoteDec` fields?

```
silly :: QuasiQuoter
silly = QuasiQuoter { quoteExp = \_ -> [| "yeah!!!" |] }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer has nothing to do with TH: if you don't initialize a field of a record constructor, trying to access that field will cause an error:

```
>data D = D {a :: Int, b :: Char} deriving Show
>D {a = 0}
D {a = 0, b = *** Exception: <interactive>:26:1-9: Missing field in record construction :Interactive.b
```

In this case, this is desired behavior since certain quoters only make sense in a certain context, and should throw an error if they are used improperly. Although, you would most likely want to provide more descriptive error message for your quoters, like so:

```
quote = QuasiQuoter { 
   quoteExp = something, 
   quotePat = error "quote: Invalid application in pattern context." ....
```

Comment: Oh so record syntax allows "incomplete" constructions in contrast to the typical data constructors allowed for the more common syntax for algebraic datatypes? Where in the documentation is this talked about in detail?

Comment: Well, you can achieve the same semantics by just putting undefined in an ordinary constructor, eg Just undefined.

Comment: I actually can't find the documentation specifically on the traditional record syntax. Maybe it doesn't even exist; record syntax is really more of an afterthought in Haskell. In any case, it is just syntactic sugar; the datatype mentioned above will defined two functions `a :: D -> Int` and `b :: D -> Char`, as I'm sure you know. Record updates are just function application. And `D {a = 0}` is just equivalent to `D 0 (error "Missing field in record construction")`.